# How to create listener in angular 2 and ionic 2

Tags: angular, listener, ionic2

i want to create listener for listen web service response. i made chat app. in that simply call my webservice and after completeion of work it gave response .problem is here there is no time fix for response so i think that i should implement listener that listen web service. Is there any way of create listener in ionic 2 and angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript and many other languages, you will handle the response of calling a web service using asynchronous programming.

The gist of this is you provide a callback method to handle the response.

```
function handleResponse(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

callService(data, handleResponse, handleError);
```

This is very different from synchronous programming where you would do something like the following:

```
var response = callService(data);
console.log(response);
```

With asynchronous programming many callbacks can depend on each other. This is called callback hell.

A more modern approach in JavaScript is to use promises. A promise is an object with subscription methods for when the promise has been fulfilled.

```
callService(data).then(handleResponse);
```

Now with Angular2 the Http service for calling web services can either return a promise or a Rxjs object.

Rxjs is like a promise. If you are familiar with the Pub/Sub pattern, think of Rxjs like Pub/Sub but internal to an application. Another way to conceptualize Rxjs is as promises for streams. Where a Promise can be resolved once, a Rxjs object can be resolved continually.

Please post the code to your service and a component that calls it. We can help you.

I am not sure that Http (I am assuming when you say `web service` you mean a Http Web Service) is the proper protocol for a Chat app. You may want to look into WebSockets or WebRTC.